# How to fix The terminal process "/usr/sbin/nologin" failed to launch (exit code: 1) error in VSCode

Tags: linux, bash, docker, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am running my VSCode on Windows but I have it connected  to a remote container. I am trying to start an integrated terminal on VSCode in that container and I get this error:

> The terminal process "/usr/sbin/nologin" failed to launch (exit code: 1).

I can enter the container and start a bash terminal with `docker exec` but the integrated VSCode terminal gives me the error mentioned above.

Any ideas,how can I successfully open the terminal in VSCode?

Comment: Can you or can you not launch /usr/sbin/nologin manually? That's the first question I'd ask, in the spirit of extracting a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hey thanks for the reply. What do you mean launch /usr/sbin/nologin? From what I gather this is a dummy terminal path used to stop specific users from having terminal access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here
[nologin - Man Page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nologin.8.html)

nologin will always exit non-zero

I expect the user associated with the container has nologin set as their default Shell.  Change this to bash or similar and you should be good to go.  You could try adding the following to your Dockerfile

`ENV SHELL /bin/bash`

Comment: yeah thanks!  I  changed the default terminal from VSCode to `shell` and it worked that makes sense now.  So for completeness what I did was `ctrl + shift + P` and then I typed `Terminal: Select Default Profile` and changed it to `shell`